# Utilisation du pronom "son" dans le sens général

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Le titre d'un [article](http://www.lemonde.fr/campus/article/2017/05/29/cinq-applications-pour-ameliorer-son-anglais_5135616_4401467.html) du *Monde*:

> Cinq applications pour améliorer son anglais

L'utilisation du pronom *son* ici est curieuse pour moi. Normalement je m'attendrais à *Cinq applications pour améliorer **votre** anglais*. Pourquoi utilise-on *son* ? À qui renvoie le pronom ?

Comment: C'est la même utilisation que le "on" général plutôt que "vous". "Votre" s'adresserait aux lecteurs alors que "son" est général.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est comme ça que l'on parle de personne en particulier. "Son" ne s'applique pas juste à quelqu'un qui lirait l'article, les conseils sont valables pour tout le monde. En anglais, on est obligé de passer par *you*/*your*, mais ça limite un peu. Dans certains cas on utilisera *them*/*their*.

Par exemple à la fin d'un examen, si le prof dit "tout le monde pose son stylo !", c'est comme si il disait à chaque personne "pose ton stylo".

De la même façon, toutes les phrases sans sujet précis (commençant par "il faut" par exemple) utilisent ce pronom :

> Il faut savoir prendre son temps
>
> Le plus important, c'est de rester soi-même
>
> Chacun pour soi (*every man for himself*)

Si j'avais utilisé "rester toi-même", ça m'exclurait alors que le conseil est valable pour tout le monde, moi y compris.

*One's* et *oneself* s'en rapprochent mais reste peu utilisés et ne conviennent pas dans la plupart des situations.

Answer (score 4):

*Son* renvoie dans ce contexte à toute personne qui lirait le titre de l'article. Il permet de ne pas s'adresser à une personne en particulier, mais bien à toute personne qui pourrait lire cet article et l'utiliser afin d'améliorer **ses** propres capacités en anglais. *Votre* pourrait également être utilisé sans problème, mais il aurait alors le sens de l'auteur qui s'adresse directement aux lecteurs pour les aider à améliorer leur anglais. *Son* est plus personnel, et apporte la sensation que l'on va soi-même améliorer son anglais à l'aide de l'article, là où *votre* donnerait plus l'impression que c'est l'auteur qui nous aide à nous améliorer.

Comment: Exactement, cela renvoie à toute personne qui désire améliorer son anglais.